# Clojure Immutant 2 server Undertow; how to handle http POST?

Tags: clojure, http-post, paypal-ipn, undertow, immutant

Putting the following line into my `compojure` `defroutes` to use `clojure-paypal-ipn` calling the two handler functions.

```
(POST "/paypal/ipn" [] (make-ipn-handler payment/paypal-data payment/paypal-error))
```

How do I handle a `POST` request within Immutant?

I'm using Immutant 2.0 with Clojure 1.7-beta1 and building off the Immutant feature demo. Posting directly with cURL give these same results, although I'm trying to use PayPal IPN.

```
17:29:40.220 ERROR [io.undertow.request] (XNIO-1 task-1) Undertow request failed HttpServerExchange{ POST /paypal/ipn}
java.io.IOException: mark/reset not supported
    at java.io.InputStream.reset(InputStream.java:348) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at clojure.lang.Reflector.invokeMatchingMethod(Reflector.java:93) ~[clojure-1.7.0-beta1.jar:na]
    at clojure.lang.Reflector.invokeNoArgInstanceMember(Reflector.java:313) ~[clojure-1.7.0-beta1.jar:na]
    at clojure_paypal_ipn.core$req__GT_raw_body_str.invoke(core.clj:59) ~[na:na]
    at clojure_paypal_ipn.core$make_ipn_handler$fn__16823.invoke(core.clj:69) ~[na:na]
    at compojure.response$eval6101$fn__6102.invoke(response.clj:34) ~[na:na]
    at compojure.response$eval6068$fn__6069$G__6059__6076.invoke(response.clj:7) ~[na:na]
    at compojure.core$make_route$fn__7513.invoke(core.clj:113) ~[na:na]
    at compojure.core$wrap_route_middleware$fn__7509.invoke(core.clj:103) ~[na:na]
    at compojure.core$if_route$fn__7488.invoke(core.clj:41) ~[na:na]
    at compojure.core$if_method$fn__7480.invoke(core.clj:27) ~[na:na]
    at compojure.core$routing$fn__7519.invoke(core.clj:127) ~[na:na]
    at clojure.core$some.invoke(core.clj:2568) ~[clojure-1.7.0-beta1.jar:na]
    at compojure.core$routing.doInvoke(core.clj:127) ~[na:na]
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:139) ~[clojure-1.7.0-beta1.jar:na]
    at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:630) ~[clojure-1.7.0-beta1.jar:na]
    at compojure.core$routes$fn__7523.invoke(core.clj:132) ~[na:na]
    at immutant.web.internal.undertow$wrap_undertow_session$fn__5292.invoke(undertow.clj:69) ~[na:na]
    at immutant.web.internal.undertow$create_http_handler$reify__5362.handleRequest(undertow.clj:130) ~[na:na]
    at org.projectodd.wunderboss.web.async.websocket.UndertowWebsocket$2.handleRequest(UndertowWebsocket.java:96) ~[wunderboss-web-0.6.1.jar:na]
    at io.undertow.server.session.SessionAttachmentHandler.handleRequest(SessionAttachmentHandler.java:68) ~[undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:197) ~[undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:759) ~[undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_45]
```

Comment: I've posted a [followup question about the underlying problem about POST input streams being eaten by other handlers in ring/compojure.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29860707/compojure-handler-friend-authenticate-eats-body-of-post-request)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think this is necessarily a problem with Immutant handling a POST. The problem occurs during the dispatch to the IPN handler, which is attempting to invoke `reset` on Undertow's `InputStream`. I would expect the stream's `markSupported` method to return false. It's not clear to me why reset is being called [here](https://github.com/smallhelm/clojure-paypal-ipn/blob/master/src/clojure_paypal_ipn/core.clj#L59), since it doesn't appear `mark` is ever called. Without being familiar with that library, I might suggest buffering the input somehow... maybe invoke `parse-paypal-ipn-string` directly? I'm really just guessing, though.

Comment: Thanks! From other discussions I gather that some handlers will read the InputStream and leave the `:body` data unavailable. I've made a [pull request to make the resets optional](https://github.com/smallhelm/clojure-paypal-ipn/pull/2).