# How can I use ring anti-forgery / CSRF token with latest version ring/compojure?

Tags: clojure, ring, compojure, csrf-protection

I copied some old code that was working in compojure 1.1.18 and other old libs, but using the latest versions I can't get it to work.

Here's my [minimal example code](https://github.com/sventech/CSRF) copied from [the minimal example here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20430281/set-ring-anti-forgery-csrf-header-token) to demonstrate that with latest ring and compojure libraries, I get an error when I send an http `POST`, even with the header set.

`lein ring server` to start it, then do

`curl -X GET --cookie-jar cookies "http://localhost:3000/"` which results in something like this:

```
{"csrf-token":"7JnNbzx8BNG/kAeH4bz1jDdGc7zPC4TddDyiyPGX3jmpVilhyXJ7AOjfJgeQllGthFeVS/rgG4GpkUaF"}
```

But when I do this

```
curl -X POST -v --cookie cookies -F "email=someone@gmail.com" --header "X-CSRF-Token: 7JnNbzx8BNG/kAeH4bz1jDdGc7zPC4TddDyiyPGX3jmpVilhyXJ7AOjfJgeQllGthFeVS/rgG4GpkUaF" http://localhost:3000/send
```

I get `<h1>Invalid anti-forgery token</h1>`

Am I doing something wrong?

The code I borrowed [was intended to answer this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20430281/set-ring-anti-forgery-csrf-header-token).

Comment: shot in the dark but does escaping the forward slashes (in the token) using backslashes make any difference?

Comment: Thanks! James Reeves / weavejester, the author of compojure and [maintainer of ring anti-forgery told me that the new `wrap-defaults` and `site-defaults` in the `ring-defaults` package](https://github.com/ring-clojure/ring-anti-forgery/issues/10) that replaces the deprecated compojure `handler` namespace automatically require CSRF tokens for HTTP `POST` et al. So my code generates the token twice and I verify against the wrong one. I'm working on a fix...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem was that `ring-defaults` (which replaces the `compojure.handler` namespace in compojure >= 1.2) automatically uses ring `anti-forgery` in the usual mode of use:

```
(defroutes app-routes
  (GET "/" [] (generate-string {:csrf-token
                                *anti-forgery-token*}))
  (POST "/send" [email] "ok")
  (resources "/")
  (not-found "Not Found"))

(def app
  (-> app-routes
   (wrap-defaults site-defaults)))
```

So two anti-forgery tokens were being generated and the `GET` request provided the invalid one. Removing the `wrap-anti-forgery` line fixed the problem.

Comment: You can mark your own question as answered if you're happy with the result.